# Zip string-subset from tuples in a list

Tags: python, string, zip

With a structure like this

```
hapts = [('1|2', '1|2'), ('3|4', '3|4')]
```

I need to `zip` it (sort of...) to get the following:

```
end = ['1|1', '2|2', '3|3', '4|4']
```

I started working with the following code:

```
zipped=[] 
for i in hapts:    
    tete = zip(i[0][0], i[1][0]) 
    zipped.extend(tete)
    some = zip(i[0][2], i[1][2])
    zipped.extend(some)
```

... and got it zipped like this:

```
zipped = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4')]
```

Any suggestions on how to continue? Furthermore i'm sure there should a more elegant way to do this, but is hard to pass to Google an accurate definition of the question ;)
Thx!

Comment: Are you _sure_ your requested output is what you want? For example, the parentheses are meaningless in what you have written.

Comment: yep, sorry! The parentheses were from previous attempts! I will edit. Thanks!

Comment: 5 answers (from 5 users with over 6k rep) and only 1 has non-negative votes (`0`) ... Something seems funny here.

Comment: Now we're heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close to solving this, I would argue the best solution here is a simple [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) in a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
["|".join(values) for values in zipped]
```

This also has the bonus of working nicely with (potentially) more values, without modification.

If you wanted tuples (which is not what your requested output shows, as brackets don't make a tuple, a comma does), then it is trivial to add that in:

```
[("|".join(values), ) for values in zipped]
```

Also note that `zipped` can be produced more effectively too:

```
>>> zipped = itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*[part.split("|") for part in group]) for group in hapts)
>>> ["|".join(values) for values in zipped]
['1|1', '2|2', '3|3', '4|4']
```

And to show what I meant before about handling more values elegantly:

```
>>> hapts = [('1|2|3', '1|2|3', '1|2|3'), ('3|4|5', '3|4|5', '3|4|5')]
>>> zipped = itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*[part.split("|") for part in group]) for group in hapts)
>>> ["|".join(values) for values in zipped]
['1|1|1', '2|2|2', '3|3|3', '3|3|3', '4|4|4', '5|5|5']
```

Comment: @peixe The output matches what you requested (see the link in my comment), what didn't work?

Comment: @Marcin [Yes, it does.](http://ideone.com/hGo8Nf) I compare directly the result of my script against the requested output he gave, and they compare equal.

Comment: @Lattyware No. Where are the tuples?

Comment: @Marcin There are no tuples in the requested output.

Comment: @Lattyware What else does OP want if not tuples, given (a) the tuples in the input and (b) the brackets in the requested output?

Comment: @Marcin It seems weirder to me to want tuples with a single element in, without an explanation given, I chose the route that seemed most likely to me.

Comment: +1: This will generate the output as Parenthesis are redundant

Comment: Yes, this will do the trick! I didnt specified if I wanted the tuples because they were not strictly necessary. I had tried with `.join` but not in the way you provided.

Comment: I still have a -1 on this one, any explanation?

Comment: +1! 
With the last edit, this does the whole thing! So I will choose it as the right solution. Thanks, @Lattyware!

Comment: @peixe No worries - be careful about the use of brackets, as this question has shown, they can cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this context is to

- unfold the list
- reformat it
- fold it

Here is how you may approach the problem

```
>>> reformat = lambda t: map('|'.join,  izip(*(e.split("|") for e in  t)))
>>> list(chain(*(reformat(t) for t in hapts)))
['1|1', '2|2', '3|3', '4|4']
```

You don't need the working code in this context

Instead if you need to work on your output, just rescan it and join it with "|"

```
>>> ['{}|{}'.format(*t) for t in zipped]
['1|1', '2|2', '3|3', '4|4']
```

**Note**

Parenthesis are redundant in your output

Answer (score 0):

```
end = []
for groups in hapts:
    end.extend('|'.join(regrouped) for regrouped in zip([group.split('|') for group in groups]))
```

This should also continue to work with n-length groups of n-length pipe-delimited characters, and n-length groups of groups, though it will truncate the regrouped values to the shortest group of characters in each group of character groups.

Comment: Have you tried this at all? Just to be explicit: you are nowhere near a solution to the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oops, didn't notice the order of values in `end`.  Forgive me, it's early...

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically works, but here's a more elegant way to do it.

First define a transposition function that takes an entry of `hapts` and flips it:

```
>>> transpose = lambda tup: zip(*(y.split("|") for y in tup))
```

Then map that function over `hapts`:

```
>>> map(transpose, hapts)
... [[('1', '1'), ('2', '2')], [('3', '3'), ('4', '4')]]
```

and then if you want to flatten this into one list

```
>>> y = list(chain.from_iterable(map(transpose, hapts)))
... [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4')]
```

Finally, to join it back up into strings again:

```
>>> map("|".join, y)
... ['1|1', '2|2', '3|3', '4|4']
```

Comment: @Marcin Oops, I forgot the last line. Thanks.